# Restricting inheritance

Tags: c++

> class BaseA{}; , class DerivedB{}; class DerivedC{};

DerivedB can be derived from BaseA : Want to allow: class DerivedB: public BaseA

But, if someone tries to do DerivedC : public BaseA ==> want to restrict this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make all `BaseA`'s constructors private and add `DerivedB` as a `friend` of `BaseA`'s.

```
class BaseA
{
    friend class DerivedB;
private:
    BaseA();
};
class DerivedB : BaseA
{
};
class DerivedC : BaseA  //error - I get it when I try to create an object in MSVS
                        //but in principle it works
{
};
```

Comment: This is only useful if one assumes that `BaseA` isn't usable on its own.

Comment: @ildjarn not necessarily, you can create instances of BaseA through, say, public static methods from it... But it's a fair point. If you need to do this, your design is fishy at least...